# Fetching changeset list via GIT

Tags: git

We have recently moved new version control GIT (earlier we used to work on TFS 2008), we had .net utility which used to communicate with TFS and used to give list of change sets (input parameter is data time to the utility) and exports to a text file.

I want equivalent/similar command in GIT, i found below command

**git diff --name-status `git log --reverse --since="2012-11-13" --until="1012-11-15" --format=format:%H | sed -n '1p;$p**

the above command will give the overall changes made to repository (for example the changes done on xyz folder), what i want is if there are sub folders inside a repository under GIT, i need to pass the path (folder or sub folder) so that i will get the changeset to specific directory rather than getting all the details of xyz.

Thanks,
Chetan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with sed? And is this what you want?

*git log --name-status --since="2012-11-1" --until="2012-11-15" --format="format:%H" **wp-content***
(where wp-content is the subdirectory to 'read')

Comment: Thank you very much!! :), i am able to get the list of change sets with the above command

Comment: My pleasure, learned something myself too (the date range args) :D

Comment: Hi Now want to achieve this using git.exe(C:\Program Files\GIT\bin\git.exe\) and not from git bash, when i trying to execute the command following via command prompt 
C:\Program Files\Git\bin>git.exe log --name-status --since="2012-11-1" --until="
2012-11-27" --format="format:%H" "D:/Git/ABC/Product/FeatureA when i execute the above command i am getting following error:       fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git i am i missing any thing here ?

Comment: That command is meant to be ran in a shell, when you run it it expects to find a git repo in the directory you run it from. If your not using shell, your prolly better off just installing some gui, heres a list http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis